# What length does a unique key need to be secure and reliably unique?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, token, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm looking to generate a unique key/token for my Invites model. Example usage:

```
mysite.com/invites/XXXXXX
```

Where XXXXXX is the unique key/token... I'm using Rails 5 for my API and learned Rails 5 has a new way to generate a secure token like so:

```
Model
    has_secure_token :access_token
```

The current Rails method creates a very LONG, unfriendly token: `973acd04bc627d6a0e31200b74e2236`

My question: Does the token really need to be that long for a model like Invites which expire, meaning tokens are not permanent. Ideally I believe the UX is better with a shorter length token so the token doesn't appear like a bug to a user.

Does anyone know of any recommendations on token length for non-permanent tokens like invite URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the token really need to be that long

Well it doesn't always need to. Normally in Rails we use [*SecureRandom*](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/SecureRandom) to generate such unique tokens. You can always get the tokens of desired length like below and use those.

```
SecureRandom.hex(10) # => "52750b30ffbc7de3b362"
SecureRandom.hex(3)  #=> "71edbe"
```

Comment: Of course, the shorter it is, the more chances of repetition.